# SFMC 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, cloudpagesurl

Can someone help me figure out where the broken code is that is making my cloud page render a 500 - internal server error? I was already trying to fix why the code was not updating the All Sub table when "Submit" is clicked, now the entire cloud page isn't working.

```
%%[

SET @em =RequestParameter("email")
SET @sbkey =RequestParameter("subkey")


SET @var1 = RequestParameter("Unsubscribe")

if @var1 == "True" then
             
    VAR @skey, @jid, @reason, @lue, @lue_prop, @lue_statusCode, @overallStatus, @requestId, @Response, @Status, @Error

    SET @skey = @subscriberkey
    SET @jid = RequestParameter("jobid")
    SET @listid = RequestParameter("listdid")
    SET @batchid = RequestParameter("batchid")
    SET @reason = "AMPscript one click unsubscribe"

    SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

    SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
    SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
    SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

 else

endif  

]%%

%%[  

if RequestParameter("submit") == "UPDATE"  Redirect(concat("https://cloud.benefits.trustmarkvb.com/Thank_you"))    

endif

]%%

 <div id="container">
   <div id="logo-container" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 60px;">
      <img id="logo" src="https://image.benefits.trustmarkvb.com/lib/fe4615707564007d761471/m/1/fb4dac18-ead7-4c7a-9d30-1767e4c8d017.png">
   </div>
   <div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 1169px; height: 27px; color:#211261; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 28px; opacity: 100%; margin-bottom: 13px;">
      Preference Center  
   </div>
   <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 656px; height: 39px; color: #555555; font-family: Arial,serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">
      We have some exciting changes coming to our preference center. In the meantime, if you really want to opt out of our Voluntary Benefits emails, please check the box below.
   </div>
   <!-- checkbox and text container-->
   <div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 60px;">
      <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border:4px; height: 19px; width:19px; margin-right: 11px;">
         <input id="Unsubscribe" type="checkbox" name="Unsubscribe" value="true" %%=v(IIF(@Unsubscribe, "checked", ""))=%%>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 487px; height: 53px; color: #555555; font-size: 16px; line-height: 18px; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 30px;">
         I would like to unsubscribe from Trustmark Valuntary Benefits emails. I understand I may still receive email from other Trustmark entities. If I decide to come back, I can simply uncheck this box.
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
      <form>
         <input id="Submit" type="Submit" name="Submit" value="UPDATE" style="top: 395px; left: 578px; width: 125px; height: 40px; color: white;
            background: #211261 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; border: 1px solid #211261; border-radius: 4px; opacity: 1;"> 
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `if-then` is missing a `then` after `if RequestParameter("submit") == "UPDATE"`.

Comment: And just like that I feel silly!  Thanks Adam!

Comment: Plus you have three variables for subscriberkey: `@skey`, `@sbkey` and `@subscriberkey`. unless there is more code around, `@subscriberkey` is currently undefined, which makes `@skey` undefined. Hence there can be no update to the subscriber. So probably make `SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)` use `@sbkey` instead and get rid of the two other unused vars.